# Thread racing, why do threads work so?

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, thread-safety

I have two different result from exchanging two lines of code ( *done = true with Console.Write() one* )

If I put done = true, firstly, the result will be:
*True*

Else If I put Console.WriteLine() firstly, the result will be:
*False
False*

Why? ( see carefully, that bool variable is static! )

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static bool done;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(test).Start();
        test();
    }

    static void test()
    {
        if (!done)
        {
            done = true;
            Console.WriteLine(done);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be even more surprised to occasionally (but probably extremely rarely) see "True True" printed with the posted code.

Comment: Incredible naivety, even didn't try to read any theory on thread safety issue in C#...and what locks, monitors, semaphors, mutexes, etc have been invented for...

Answer (score 8):

My bet is that the `Console.WriteLine` will be enough work to keep the thread busy while the second call to `test()` has a chance to execute.

So basically the call to `WriteLine` delays the setting of `done` long enough for the second call to `test` to be able to test `done` and find it is still set as `false`.

If you leave it as shown, with `done = true;` before the write to the console then this will be set almost instantly and thus the second call to test will find `done` set to `true` and will therefore not perform the `Console.WriteLine`.

Hope that all makes sense.

---

I just [found this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) which contains code very much like your question. If you didn't get your question from this page already, then I would suggest having a read as it explains in much more detail the cause of this effect.

With the follow key extract:

> On a single-processor computer, a thread scheduler performs
>   time-slicing — rapidly switching execution between each of the active
>   threads. Under Windows, a time-slice is typically in the
>   tens-of-milliseconds region — much larger than the CPU overhead in
>   actually switching context between one thread and another (which is
>   typically in the few-microseconds region).

So essentially the call to `Console.WriteLine` is taking long enough for the processor to decide that it is time for the main thread to have another go before your extra thread is permitted to continue (and ultimate set the `done` flag)

Comment: +1, also note that the `static` keyword emphasised in the OP does in no way mean its all thread safe.

Comment: It makes perfect sense - the Console.WriteLine call is the only substantive operation in the app and would require a lock to be taken on the output buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Your code isn't thread safe, and the results will be unpredictable.

You need to lock access when reading / writing to the static boolean, like so:

```
    static bool done;
    static readonly object _mylock = new object();
    static void Main()
    {
        //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //Application.Run(new Form1());
        new Thread(test).Start();
        test();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void test()
    {
        lock (_mylock)
        {
            if (!done)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(done);
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

*Edit* : readonly thanks @d4wn

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the scheduler just cut the CPU time from one thread after it's call of `Console.Writeline` and then gave it to the other thread, all before `done` was set to `true`.

Are you certain that it **always** prints `False\nFalse` when you call `Console.Writeline` before assigning `done = true;`? To my understanding, this should be quite random.

Comment: I'm testing now on my PC this code, while it prints ( if Console.WriteLine(done) - is first, then setting bool variable to the "true" )

Answer (score 0):

Each time a shared variable is accessed by one of the sharing threads must be protected by one of the syncronization techniques explicitly. The environment (clr..) doesn't do it for us, cause in the whole possible complexity of multithreading it would be impossible. So this definetely responsible and not easy task must be done by the developer, writing multithreading code.

I guess there you can find a great deal of necessary information:
[Thread Synchronization (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)